# Amazon Mechanical Turk Worker API

Tags: amazon-product-api, mechanicalturk

I'm making a mobile application which has a some specific survey. So the goal is to integrate this app with crowdsourcing service like Amazon's MTurk. Amazon published an api's and examples for the Requester needs. But i didn't found any mentions about how to integrate Workers to application. Is there a some way to authorize MTurk Workers so they can perform HIT's directly in app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a Worker API. Some have used screen-scraping, other Workers have used GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey scripts to "work around" the lack of an API. But there is not a Worker API at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Building on jrb's response, there is not a first-class "Worker API" currently available. But a number of paths on the Worker website allow you to swap the `.html` extension with `.json` and get a JSON response. For example, turning `https://worker.mturk.com/projects` into `https://worker.mturk.com/projects.json` returns the following:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "hit_set_id": "39393HGTH46CTINJ1KWCJDBLXGLOEQ",
      "requester_id": "AKEBQYX32KM19",
      "requester_name": "Crowdsurf Support",
      "title": "Full Text Review - Earn up to $0.17 per media minute",
      "description": "Review and edit full-length transcripts",
      "assignment_duration_in_seconds": 21600,
      "creation_time": "2019-08-16T18:38:53.000Z",
      "assignable_hits_count": 433,
      "latest_expiration_time": "2020-08-06T23:08:13.000Z",
      "caller_meets_requirements": false,
      "caller_meets_preview_requirements": false,
      "last_updated_time": "2019-08-16T18:38:53.000Z",
      "monetary_reward": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "amount_in_dollars": 0.17
      },
      "accept_project_task_url": "/projects/39393HGTH46CTINJ1KWCJDBLXGLOEQ/tasks/accept_random.json?ref=w_pl_prvw",
      "requester_url": "/requesters/AKEBQYX32KM19/projects.json?ref=w_pl_prvw",
      "project_tasks_url": "/projects/39393HGTH46CTINJ1KWCJDBLXGLOEQ/tasks.json?ref=w_pl_prvw",
      "project_requirements": [
...

      ],
      "requesterInfo": {
        "activityLevel": "High",
        "taskApprovalRate": "≥ 99%",
        "taskReviewTime": "less than a day"
      }
    }
  ],
  "page_number": 1,
  "num_results": 20,
  "total_num_results": 990
}
```